# How can you add systemverilog class variables or class members to waveform?

Tags: class, system-verilog, simulator, waveform, uvm

In your systemverilog simulator (Ius/cadence, Questa/Mentor or VCS/Synopsys) you usually want to see systemverilog class variables in the waveform.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

In **Questasim** >10.2 it is possible to add class variables  to the waveform display.
There are three possible ways.

1. Using **-classdebug** flag in vsim
   If you add the -classdebug flag then you will be able to activate the pane:
   *View->class Browser->Class instances*
   Inside that pane you can see all the **member variables** (only variables no methods) inside a selected **systemverilog** class.

[image: Adding systemverilog class to waveform in Questasim]

2. Without using **-classdebug** flag in vsim but using the UVM_ROOT hierarchy.

With this method. You can add to the waveform systemverilog class members that are inside UVM_ROOT hierarchy, that is, classes that are UVM COMPONENTS. That excludes all the class variables inside UVM_OBJECTS like sequences and sequence items.
[image: UVM_ROOT COMPONENTS USED TO ADD SYSTEMVERILOG CLASS VARIABLES TO WAVEFORM]

3. Without Using **-classdebug** but with breakpoint insertion

**See internal variables of a task in the waveform**

To view the internal variables to a task, you have to view the variables during the time it is executing.  They can be viewed in the Locals/Watch window by following these steps:

1. Open the Locals window by View->Locals (It will be empty initially)
2. Set a breakpoint inside the task of the class for which you want to see the local variable values. When sim breaks, you can see the  object in the Locals Window.
3. Open the Watch window by View->Watch
4. Click and drag the task variables for that instance from the Locals into the Watch window to view them there.  If you have instanced other classes, you can simply double-click on the item and it will open up nearby with its own members.

   It is possible to view these variables in the **Wave window**, however it is not an easy process due to the dynamic nature of a task in a class.  Here is some further discussion on this:
   At the moment, there’s no way to capture the paths to the different sets of local variables in each activation of a class method except through interactive debugging where you can set a breakpoint in the middle of one of those activations and examine the stack/thread frames. From there you can open the Locals window (View->Local) and drag the variables to the Watch **or Wave Windows**.

**The recommend approach** is to move the declaration of the local variable outside the class method to become a member of the class, and proceed to log the class instance. If that change is not possible because it changes the behavior of the method, therein lies what makes logging local variables problematic. The behavior would change if the method is re-entrant – meaning there could be multiple simultaneous activations of the same method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link for the same.

https://verificationacademy.com/verification-horizons/june-2014-volume-10-issue-2/Visualizer-Debug-Environment-Class-based-Testbench-Debugging-using-a-New-School-Debugger-Debug-This

You can also visit my blog, in which I have shared this link. 
http://vlsi-random.blogspot.in/2016/10/debugging-on-class-based-testbench.html

Comment: Agree. I thought of putting it as an answer, only because I found it a bit lengthy for a comment. Anyways I'll take care of it from now. :)

Comment: Both links are not valid. Could you please update if you can?